# NestJS redirect HTTP to HTTPS / force SSL

Tags: typescript, security, https, nestjs

Building a NestJS Application I want to route ALL incoming traffic through https without inconvenience for the user.

So far there are two ways I know, both doesn't fit my requirements.

1. Set up two servers for http and https and than redirect traffic per route/api endpoint, which is really not DRY and cannot be best practice. [Doc redirect](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection)
2. By only creating the https server, the user would always be forced to type the https address manually what I don't want. [Doc https](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/multiple-servers)

Ideally I would assume a solution where https is checked and forced the very first moment some one is hitting the server by just typing `example.com`. I think this would best be done in `main.ts` of my NestJS application.

Comment: You can do this easily on nginx level. Is this solution good enough to you?

Comment: I am not familiar with nginx, right now I am serving my nestjs build via `node main.js`, nothing fancy. I am open for changes if they provide benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For production release you will probably use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/). Nginx will be listen on port 80 and redirect to nestJS port. Advantage of this solution is easy redirecting to https. In you config you can put something like this

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    example1.com example2.com;
       return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    example1.com example2.com;
       ...
}
```

So each http request will be redirect to https. And your application don't have to care about http request because each of them will be redirect before.

Comment: So basically I could do the same thing with an Apache Server? I already have one set up.

Comment: Yes, this two solutions are very similar. You can define redirect on apache as well.

Answer (score 7):

For my use case, I see no reason to bloat the server with reverse proxy layer while node http servers are fully featured. Since question is related to NestJS, here I present simple native solution, using Nest middleware. Of course, u will have to also follow the NestJS documentation on hosting two servers, which is again fairly simple.

```
import { HttpStatus, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from "express";

@Injectable()
export class HttpsRedirectMiddleware implements NestMiddleware
{
    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void)
    {
        if (!req.secure)
        {
            const httpsUrl = `https://${req.hostname}${req.originalUrl}`;
            res.redirect(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT, httpsUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            next();
        }
    }
}
```

We simply ask on request object whether conneciton is secure, if not, we incite browser to permanently redirect to same url, but this time prefixed with `https://`.
The middleware class above is then to be registered for all routes within `configure()` method of `AppModule`.

```
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer)
{
    consumer.apply(HttpsRedirectMiddleware).forRoutes("*");
}
```

Comment: Is the port (80, 8080 or sth. like this) already included in `req.hostname`?

Comment: @BennyCode the port is not included in req.hostname

Comment: Just a warning for Heroku users, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Heroku Users

`npm install express-sslify --save`

Then, in your `main.ts` file:

```js
import enforce from 'express-sslify';

async bootstrap() {
    // create your app

    // Must be the FIRST middleware applied
    // Must add in the 'trustProtoHeader' option
    // (I only add this for production, but you can do whatever suits you)
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true });
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

If your NestJS application is hosted on Heroku, you cannot have 2 servers running on an HTTP and HTTPS port. You also cannot simply redirect to `https`, because Heorku sends the data from their outward-facing load balancers internally over HTTP traffic, and the app will redirect infinitely.

See [Heroku Docs](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls)
and [express-sslify docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify), especially the section there regarding Heroku.